# How to use href with onClick() in IonButton?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

The below onClick() function works as intended without href. But when I add in the href, only the href seems to run, not the onClick() function. How do I both run the onClick() function and also send the user to a new page?

```
                <IonButton
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={() => {saveData()}}
                    href="/create/"
                >Save</IonButton>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not really want to use `href` use `history`

```
const history = useHistory();
```

```
<IonButton color="primary"
  onClick={(event) => { 
      event.preventDefault();
      saveData(); 
      history.push("/create")}}
> Save
</IonButton>
```

Answer (score 2):

`preventDefault()` method of a JS `event` will restrict the JS engine to execute the default functionality of the HTML tag to be performed on any event. Which in your case is, navigating to the URL mentioned in `href` attribute of `<a>` tag.

Call `preventDefault` of the click event in the handler like following:

```
const history = useHistory();

// ....

const saveData = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  // here you can implement your logic
  history.push("/create");
}
```

Comment: So i'm more asking what the best way to "not" prevent default is while also using onClick. right now i just put window.location.href in the onClick function but, well, maybe that's fine? it doesn't seem like it fits into the react or ionic framework well though

Comment: As ReactJS is a SPA styled library. it uses only static routing. if you do window.location.href, it will reload the complete page. which will be a re-render of App.js. 
So, using a library like react-router-dom, you can redirect to another React Route, Also, it will be using the Link component instead of the <a> tag.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, ty!