# Ionic Button click navigate to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

Hi I have a little problem using the ionic framework on react, what i want is when i click the login button it will navigate to homepage, the current behavior in my code is when typing in the browser url `/homepage` it works well but when clicking the button login it didnt navigate to homepage, I dont know why, any ideas?

Login.tsx

```
const Login: React.FC = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const homepage = () =>{
        console.log("ss")
        history.push("/homepage");
    }
    return (
           .....
           <IonButton   onClick={homepage}  color="success" shape="round" size='default' className='submitButton'>
           <span className='login-button'>Login</span>
           </IonButton>
    )
}
```

App.tsx

```
const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Route exact path="/login">
          <Login/>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/homepage" component={Homepage}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        </Route>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
);
```

Comment: See please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237684/how-to-use-href-with-onclick-in-ionbutton